# Dynamic Stretch DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to align 3 divs side by side. 2 of them have fixed width but the last one has to stretch the remaining area of the page. My container's width: 1000px. Fixed divs'widths are 200px. If there is no 200px div, last one's width will be 1000px. ıf there is just one 200px that is float to left, last one's width will be 800px. Also if there is just one 200px that is float to right, last one's width will be 800px again and it will float left. But if there are 2 200px div on the page, last one's width will be 600px it will placed between that left 200px and right 200px divs. How can I do that?

I'm trying to do that:

i45.tinypic.com/5d1nxe.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366469/dynamic-stretch ?

Comment: Use `display: table;`

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9J9Yc

After the stars there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm serving as Google here, but check these out:

1. [Flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)
2. [Instructions/Tutorial for use of the flexbox model.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/)

You'd want to set up your hypothetical like this:

```
div.container{
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal
}
div.container div.child {
  width: 200px;
}
div.container div.child:nth-child(3) {
  box-flex: 1;
}
```

Voila, that should do exactly what you're looking for.  However, you'll need to use the vendor specific prefixes/properties to implement this as it's in experimental implementation in everything except IE10.

Comment: Flexbox support among browsers is [very weak](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: It is an emerging standard.  The alternative is to use Javascript or the display:table / display:table-cell which has its own hurdles with wonky implementation.  Unfortunately, there is no silver bullet solution for this issue.

Comment: it's very useful but all of them for new browsers. Is there a way to do it with using css2?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: [I've updated my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/9J9Yc/1/) using nth-child selectors to determine what should be done with the "auto-expanding" div by predicting the handful of places it can occur.

---

If you float a fixed-width `div` either side of a `div` with no width, the latter `div` will expand automatically.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmjAX/)

Getting it to work for your different circumstances is as simple as changing the float values or re-arranging your markup.

Comment: It's not working when I do that;

<div class="container">
    <div class="auto">This stretches to 800px</div>
    <div class="block">200px wide</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="block">200px wide</div>
    <div class="auto">This stretches to 800px</div>
    <div class="block">200px wide</div>
</div>

Comment: Could you post an example on jsfiddle of the specific HTML and CSS you're using that's not working for you?

Comment: Left and right divs are depends on the user. He can add or not the 200px divs to the page. So the page has to appear such as in the pic.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another method. I haven't fully tested it, but it should be possible to cover any situation you'll encounter with this set up. I can go into more detail later, just rushing off right now. Edit: I should mention it's not truly auto-expanding - so this particular CSS will only work for the given circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:1000px; ">
<div id="divA" style="width: 200px; float: left; background-color: blue;">a</div>
<div id="divB" style="float: left; width:600px; background-color: yellow;">b</div>
<div id="divC" style="width: 200px; float: left; background-color: red;">c</div>
</div>
<script>
    if(document.getElementById("divA") == null && document.getElementById("divC") == null) {  document.getElementById("divB").style.width="1000"}
    else if (document.getElementById("divA") == null || document.getElementById("divC") == null)  {  document.getElementById("divB").style.width="800"}
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me when tested.  Would like to hear the down-vote comment.